# Creating a Blank Site with SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Here is my environment:

```
SharePoint Server 2013 Trial
SharePoint Designer 2013
```

When I create a blank site in SharePoint Designer 2013, an error message shows saying:

```
This template is not supported on http://<server name>
```

However, when I create a Blog site or Team Site, the site creation will be successful.

When I create a new subsite via SharePoint Server 2013, there is no Blank website option.

Is it possible to create a blank site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blank site template is not visible in SharePoint, because its "Hidden" property is set to true (see [this blog entry](http://itproafrica.com/technology/sharepoint/sharepoint-2013-oh-wherefore-art-thou-blank-site-template/) on how to change this setting, if you don't mind editing configuration files yourself). Another option to create a blank subsite is to create it using PowerShell:

```
$s = Get-SPSite "<URL of your Site Collection>"
$template = Get-SPWebTemplate -Identity "STS#1"
$s.AllWebs.Add("SubsiteUrl", "Name", "Description", 1033, $template, $false, $false)
```

The Url of the Subsite is relative to the URL of the Site Collection. See [this Technet article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebcollection.add.aspx) for further details on how to create the subsite.